# Movie where the hero is able to respawn into a new robot shell every time he dies

Tags: story-identification, movie

Okay, so here's everything I remember about this movie:

1) It was on YouTube for free. Possibly posted by the creators.

2) the main character transfers his consciousness from one robot shell to another every time he dies, retaining all of his memories up until then.

3) The plot went something like this: It starts with him busting some kind of drug den, "recklessly" wasting one shell just to scope out the room. The movie's creators must have been using that scene to demonstrate his powers to the audience. Then one of the facilities that provides the shells for him gets compromised, so he can no longer respawn. With one shell remaining, he has to travel to China to track down the source of the attack: a sentient AI accidentally created by a teenage hacker. She had written a virus (disguised as a game of mahjong) that was distributed on secure supercomputers across the world, but it evolved apparently. The movie ends when the main character talks to the AI and sort of lets it... absorb his consciousness.

In between all of this, there's a bunch of shooting, a motorcycle chase or two, a fireside chat, and a girlfriend who thinks the main character is dead. Ring any bells?

Comment: Are you sure it's a he? Because this sounds a lot like Ghost In the Shell 2017 movie.

Comment: Is the word "respawn" from the movie, or is it your own invention? What does it mean?

Comment: Respawn is first-person shooter term. Or computer game term, if you will. A character dies, his body stays there, a life is spent... Then a new body, the same as the previous one, shows up at designated place. There could also be respawning enemies: You kill every enemy in the room, get out of the room, get back in the room and they are all alive again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is **[Sync](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2317127/)**. The youtube web-series (now a film) featured bodyhopping and a botnet based on Mahjong...